# Android Configuration Change

Tags: android, configuration, imageview

What happens to the width and height params declared in LayoutParams on configuration change?

For eg: if I have an ImageView declared with, 
new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 40);

On Configuration Change, does the width become 40 and height 30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope... they will remain the same.